# Create a callable button inside a view class discord.py

Tags: python, class, discord.py, pycord, callable-object

I want to create a callable button from a personalised button class.

I have seen on [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kNUuYEWGOxA) that you can call button such as:

```py
@discord.ui.button(label="Hola")
    # Callback function that disable the button and reply to the user
    async def button_callback(self, button, interaction):
        button.disabled = True
        await interaction.response.edit_message(view=self)
        await interaction.followup.send('Hello!')
```

I'm trying to make something like this:

```py
class MyView(View):
    @GreenButtons('Hello There!')
    async def button_callback(self, button, interaction):
        button.disabled = True
        await interaction.response.edit_message(view=self)
        await interaction.followup.send('General Kenobi!')
```

I've been thinking about adding a `__call__` function, but it didn't work out quite well.

```py
class GreenButtons(Button):
    def __init__(self, label):
        super().__init__(label=label, style=discord.ButtonStyle.green)

    def __call__(self, label):
        GreenButtons(label)

    async def callback(self, interaction):
        self.disabled = True
        await interaction.response.send_message(f"{self.label} clicked!")
```

In fact, when I did start the program, it was only showing 'Testing' without buttons :

```py
async def test_view(self, ctx)
    my_view = XeMyView()
    await ctx.respond("Testing", view=my_view)
```

I'm not sure what I did wrong here. So, how can I make it work without creating every buttons inside every view class I'll have to create ?